# How to asynchronously load individual row elements of a table in PrimeFaces or JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

#### OBJECTIVE

I'm displaying a table where rows are physical computers on the local network, and the columns are some pieces of information from each individual computer. Some of this information is stored locally on the server, but some is retrieved from the computers themselves via REST requests. I would like to make the calls asynchronous for performance reasons; what I have in mind is to display the table with some placeholders initially, than send all the requests, and then gradually fill it with data as the individual requests receive their response.

#### PROBLEM

Problem is that none of the solutions I found have worked. p:outputPanel with the 'deferred' property stays in the placeholder state, displaying that spinning widget forever. remoteCommand won't fire no matter what I do. I have tried all variations of these and none have produced the desired behavior.

---

#### OTHER OBSERVATIONS

p:outputPanel is successfuly used in another place in the application, except it is for a whole table, and it works fine there. Using it on the whole table won't help, though, I still have to wait for responses from each individual computer. I could also change the API to get all the info in one request, but performance is still going to suffer one we add more computers. Request load isn't the problem here, it's the sequential waiting until requests to unresponsive computers time out.

---

Table:

```
    <p:dataTable value="#{stationController.items}" var="item" sortMode="multiple" lazy="true"
                 paginator="true" rows="50">

        <!--TestBundle Project Name-->
        <p:column sortBy="#{item.status}" filterBy="#{item.status}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.clientListTitle_testBundleProject}" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:outputPanel deferred="true">
                <h:outputText value="#{testStationsClient.getProjectName(item.ipAddress)}" />
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:column>
        <!-- bunch of more of these... -->

    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Where is the code for your attempts? I don't see any `p:outputPanel` with deferred option

Comment: One thing uou might be able to do is somehow use OmiFaces MoveComponent to add 1 row to the datatable at a time: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/moveComponent  I have seen this used as a clever trick to replace a single datatable row.

Comment: Please improve your code... You now effectively ask us to write code. We'd love to help with the original problem with the 'deferred' outputpanel, but **YOU** have to be proactive (I noticed you were online in stackoverflow less than half an hour ago). Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive (I did not downvote... yet) I seriously love to help since it is an interesting question. Cheers

Comment: EDIT: added the attempt. This is what worked when applied to a whole table elsewhere in the same application, except I left out the ID, since there would be duplicates. My reasoning was that Primefaces will take care of waiting until all the method calls are resolved and only then display the value, while displaying the swirling thingy instead until then.

Comment: @Melloware thanks for the tip; unfortunately, I don't have time to try it right now, deadline's fast approaching. I worked around the problem with a hack(decreased timeouts, so that requests to unresponsive computers fail fast instead of hanging for 5 secs each and the table is rendered in a reasonable time) that will have to do for now.